# DNS Public sub domain resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, resolution

Hypothetical question about DNS sub domain resolution- I work at a firm, whose address 209.153.206.5 resolves mycompany.com. Assuming I have a block of 5 IP addresses and map an address of 209.153.206.6 to pass through my firewall to a terminal server on our internal LAN (for example using port forwarding) at an address like terminalservices.mycompany.com... Do I need to contact my DNS provider to create the record, or will it resolve correctly automatically when the query hits the DNS? Assume the firewall is a Cisco ASA in the small end of the 5500 series.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to be picky, that's not a subdomain, it's an A host record for your domain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have DNS terminalservices.mycompany.com pointing to correct IP. This does not happen magically:) But you DNS provider could have put for you a wildcard dns for all subdomains to point to same IP lime primary domain. You just need to check what it resolves to.